# You are manually calling a React.PropTypes validation function for the `path` prop on `Route`

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-component

Getting this warning when i use router in **reactjs**.

Warning: You are manually calling a `React.PropTypes` validation function for the `path` prop on `Route`. This is deprecated and will not work in production with the next major version.

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hashHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Routing}></Route>
    </Router>, 
    document.getElementById('layout')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a problem with an old version of `react-router` while working with `React@^15.3.0`.
Only way to solve this is to update `react-router` or downgrade `react`.

Further reading:

- [react-router issue](https://github.com/erikras/react-redux-universal-hot-example/issues/1246)
- [Warning](https://facebook.github.io/react/warnings/dont-call-proptypes.html) in general